# The probability of rolling 5 dice ordered or unordered

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We roll 5 dice that have 6 faces.

If we roll them simultaneously what is the probability that no two of them are the same.

$$\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n+r-1}{r}}=\frac{\binom{6}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}$$

What is the difference between the above:

and the following:

$$\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 }{6^5}$$

In the first one we consider that they are unordered and in the second one we consider them unordered.

Comment: What things are you counting with $\binom{10}{5}$ ? Do those things occur equally often?

Comment: The difference is that the second formula calculates a probability for rolling five distinct numbers on five ordinary dice (either sequentially or all at once), whereas the first formula doesn't calculate a probability for any realistic scenario using ordinary dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying stars and bars, $ \displaystyle {5 + 6 - 1 \choose 5}$ is the number of ways in which numbers from $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ can show up on five identical dice. For example, there can be two $2'$s, three $3'$s or all $5'$s and so on.

In other words, $ \displaystyle {10 \choose 5}$ counts solutions to the number of $6$-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is $5$:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 5 ~, ~$ where $x_i$ is non-negative integer.

*But the outcomes in this sample space are not equally probable and cannot be applied to calculate probability*

To calculate probability, we first choose any $5$ numbers by $ \displaystyle {6 \choose 5}$ and  multiply by $5!$ as the chosen numbers can show up in different orders on five dice. Then we note that the probability of a particular number showing up on a die is $\dfrac 16$. So the answer is

$ \displaystyle {6 \choose 5} \cdot \frac{5!}{6^5} = \frac{5}{54}$

You can also write the probability as,

$ \displaystyle \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} = \frac{5}{54}$

That is the first die can be any number then for the second die there are $5$ choices, for the third die there are $4$ choices and so on...

Comment: Interesting, because in my combinatorics class we differentiated between throwing dices one by one and throwing them all at once whereas at my probability classes we said it is the same thing. Why is that so?

Comment: @VLC Combinatorics sometimes counts only what we see. But that is not true reflection of its likelihood of occurring. We often use a simple example to understand it. If we take two identical coins and flip them simultaneously, we are going to get $2H$, $2T$ or $1H,1T$. We would make a grave mistake if we took this sample space to find probability of both coins showing $H$ and said $1/3$.

Comment: The point is that $1H, 1T$ is twice likely to occur than the other two outcomes. So even though coins are identical, the sample space when calculating probability remains as $\{H, H\}, \{H, T\}, \{T, H\}, \{T, T\}$.

Comment: is there a wikipedia article or a question on mathstackexchange about this difference?

Comment: would we count the number of combinations that no two of them are the same in combinatorics if we throw all dice at once the way I counted them?

Comment: In numerator of the first example

Comment: Yes the numerator is counting possible combinations of five numbers out of six. The stars and bars is only being applied in the denominator to count all possible outcomes but the outcomes have different probabilities.

Comment: There are many questions on the site where this point has come up. In fact I have answered some of them myself but I am not able to find it right now. Here is one that I found: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231628/stars-and-bars-and-probabilities